# HTML <select> conditional tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple form that allows users to add clients and their locations (country, state, and city). There seems to be a problem in the code that causes the drop-down form fields to remain in place when the country is switched. For example, if the user selects *China*, followed by any Province, and then any city, and then switches the country, the drop--down for *city* still remains. This can be seen in the code snippet.

```js
function displayCountry(answer) {
  document.getElementById(answer).style.display = "block";
  if (answer == "China") {
    document.getElementById("India").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("USA").style.display = "none";
  } else if (answer == "India") {
    document.getElementById("China").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("USA").style.display = "none";
  } else if (answer == "USA") {
    document.getElementById("China").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("India").style.display = "none";
  }
}

function displayProvince(answer) {
  document.getElementById(answer).style.display = "block";
  if (answer == "Beijing Municipality") {
    document.getElementById("Tianjin Municipality").style.display = "none";
  } else if (answer == "Tianjin Municipality") {
    document.getElementById("Beijing Municipality").style.display = "none";
  }
}

function displayChinaCity(answer) {
  document.getElementById(answer).style.display = "block";
  if (answer == "Beijing") {
    document.getElementById("Dongcheng").style.display = "none";
  } else if (answer == "Dongcheng") {
    document.getElementById("Beijing").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Add Client</h3>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <form action="/add/clients" method="post">

      <div class="top-row">
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>Client ID<span class="req">*</span><input></label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="top-row">
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>Client name<span class="req">*</span><input></label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>Client type<span class= "req">*</span><select></select></label>
      </div>


      <div class="field-wrap">
      
        <label>Client Origin<span class="req">*</span>
          <select name="country" onchange="displayCountry(this.value)">
            <option selected= "--">--</option>
            <option value= "China" >China</option>
            <option value= "India" >India</option>
            <option value= "USA"  >USA</option>
          </select>
        </label>

        <div id="USA" style="display:none;">
          <select></select>
        </div>

        <div id="China" style="display:none;"><br/>
          Select Province<span class="req">*</span>
          <select name="province" onchange="displayProvince(this.value)">
            <option selected= "--">--</option>
            <option value= "Beijing Municipality" >Beijing Municipality</option>
            <option value= "Tianjin Municipality">Tianjin Municipality</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        
        <div id="India" style="display:none;">
          <select></select>
        </div>

        <div id="Beijing Municipality" style="display:none;"><br/>
          Select City<span class="req">*</span>
          <select name="city" onchange="displayChinaCity(this.value)">
            <option selected= "--">--</option>
            <option value= "Beijing">Beijing</option>
            <option value= "Dongcheng">Dongcheng</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you trying to solve this? I suggest a review on your approach to this problem.

Comment: I figured the `if-else` statements were enough to branch properly, so now I'm confused. Surely I don't have to call my `displayCountry` function within every other function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another approach to your problem. Instead of creating all `select` tags in HTML by hand, I'm making them with a function `buildForms` and using a data structure to keep all countries/states/cities in one place. I'm using the `buildSelect` function to produce all `select` tags and the functions `updateStates` and `updateCities` to hide/show the elements.

```js
var data = {
  countries: [{
    name: 'China',
    childs: [{
      name: 'Beijing',
      childs: [{name: 'Beijing'}, {name: 'Dongcheng'}]
    }, {
      name: 'Tianjin',
      childs: [{name: 'Guangzhou'}, {name: 'Shanghai'}]
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'India',
    childs: [{
      name: 'Uttar',
      childs: [{name: 'Kanpur'}, {name: 'Ghaziabad'}]
    }, {
      name: 'Maharashtra',
      childs: [{name: 'Mumbai'}, {name: 'Pune'}]
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'USA',
    childs: [{
      name: 'Washington',
      childs: [{name: 'Washington'}, {name: 'Seatle'}]
    }, {
      name: 'Florida',
      childs: [{name: 'Orlando'}, {name: 'Miamy'}]
    }]
  }]
};

function buildSelect(name, data, childs) {
  var div = $('<div>');
  div.addClass('hidden autoSelect ' + data.name + ' ' + name);
  var label = $('<label>');
  label.text(name);
  var select = $('<select>');
  var option = $('<option>');
  option.text('--');
  select.append(option);
  data.childs.forEach(function (child) {
     option = $('<option>');
     option.val(child.name);
     option.text(child.name);
     select.append(option);
  });
  if (childs) select.on('change', updateCities);
  label.append(select);
  div.append(label);
  $('.country').append(div);
}

function buildForms(data) {
  data.countries.forEach(function (country) {
     buildSelect('State', country, true);
     country.childs.forEach(function (state) {
       buildSelect('City', state);
     });
  });
}

function hideAutoSelect (name) {
  $('div.autoSelect.'+name).addClass('hidden');
}

function updateStates() {
  var v = this.value;
  if (v) {
    hideAutoSelect('State');
    hideAutoSelect('City');
    var div = $('div.autoSelect.'+v);
    div.removeClass('hidden');
    var select = $('select', div);
    if (select.val()) $('div.autoSelect.'+select.val()).removeClass('hidden');
  }
}

function updateCities() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  if (v) {
    hideAutoSelect('City');
    $('div.autoSelect.'+v).removeClass('hidden');
  }
}

$(document).on('ready',function () {
  buildForms(data);
  $('[name=country]').on('change', updateStates);
});
```

```css
.hidden {display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Add Client</h3>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <form action="/add/clients" method="post">

      <div class="top-row">
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>Client ID<span class="req">*</span>
            <input placeholder="0000000">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="top-row">
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>Client name<span class="req">*</span>
            <input placeholder="John">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>Client type<span class= "req">*</span>
          <select>
            <option selected= "--">--</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>


      <div class="field-wrap country">
      
        <label>Client Origin<span class="req">*</span>
          <select name="country">
            <option selected= "--">--</option>
            <option value= "China" >China</option>
            <option value= "India" >India</option>
            <option value= "USA"  >USA</option>
          </select>
        </label>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this actually makes sense, thank you! However, if I want to hide the `city` field until the user selects a `state`, do I just add another `hideAutoSelect`

Comment: I updated the post to hide the city field until the user selects a state.

Comment: While I can see that it works here, I can't seem to replicate the results in production via `heroku`. Did you add a gem to the Gemfile?

Comment: I really don't believe heroku or gemfiles are a problem here. Check out if you included the css `.hidden {display: none}`

Comment: I even copied and pasted this excerpt into a new file in the directory and none of the fields past the country appear. Even the placeholders for `Vendor ID` and `Vendor name` do not show.

Comment: Can you share the link? I use heroku for quite some time and I'm pretty sure it has no way of blocking this script.

Comment: Just move the script tag to before the end of the body tag.

Comment: I moved the `<script>` tag after the html portion of the code, and it worked. Although, the file is a .html.erb, so wouldn't the entire file be treated as part of the `<body>` tag? In other words, I don't understand how this fixed it

Comment: Another odd occurrence with this is that directly accessing the **/add/vendors** link is perfectly fine. But clicking through the navigation bar Add > Vendor leads to the same prior problem of the fields not appearing

Comment: Moving the script tag works cuz it only starts running after the DOM is loaded; Seems like bootstrap is preventing page refresh with XMLHttpRequest. Since you are using jquery, try `$(document).ready(...)`. I'll update the answer ;)

Comment: Since this is another issue, you should open a new question about it. Send me the link here so I can help you further.

Comment: New question can be found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435273/html-page-features-only-fully-work-upon-page-refresh-but-not-through-any-links
Thanks!