# HTML page features only fully work upon page refresh but not through any links

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have an interesting problem with one of my RoR application pages that is a bit hard to explain.

Basically, I have a page ***vendor.html.erb*** which allows the user to input data for vendors, including selecting their location (country, state, city) from dropdowns that appear depending on the country and states selected. This seems to work just fine when I refresh the web page but when I access the page through the navigation bar *(_header.html.erb)*, the dropdowns fail to appear. The input placeholders also fail to appear when accessing the page through links.

Below is my **/app/views/static_pages/vendor.html.erb**

```
<head>
<style>
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/application-258e88d.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload">
<script src="/application-cbd3cd4.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<meta name="turbolinks-visit-control" content="reload">
<script>

var data = {
  countries: [{
    name: 'China',
    childs: [{
      name: 'Beijing',
      childs: [{name: 'Beijing'}, {name: 'Dongcheng'}]
    }, {
      name: 'Tianjin',
      childs: [{name: 'Guangzhou'}, {name: 'Shanghai'}]
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'India',
    childs: [{
      name: 'Uttar',
      childs: [{name: 'Kanpur'}, {name: 'Ghaziabad'}]
    }, {
      name: 'Maharashtra',
      childs: [{name: 'Mumbai'}, {name: 'Pune'}]
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'USA',
    childs: [{
      name: 'Washington',
      childs: [{name: 'Washington'}, {name: 'Seatle'}]
    }, {
      name: 'Florida',
      childs: [{name: 'Orlando'}, {name: 'Miami'}]
    }]
  }]
};

function buildSelect(name, data, childs) {
  var div = $('<div>');
  div.addClass('hidden autoSelect ' + data.name + ' ' + name);
  var label = $('<label>');
  label.text(name);
  var select = $('<select>');
  var option = $('<option>');
  option.text('--');
  select.append(option);
  data.childs.forEach(function (child) {
     option = $('<option>');
     option.val(child.name);
     option.text(child.name);
     select.append(option);
  });
  if (childs) select.on('change', updateCities);
  label.append(select);
  div.append(label);
  $('.country').append(div);
}

function buildForms(data) {
  data.countries.forEach(function (country) {
     buildSelect('State', country, true);
     country.childs.forEach(function (state) {
       buildSelect('City', state);
     });
  });
}

function hideAutoSelect (name) {
  $('div.autoSelect.'+name).addClass('hidden');
}

function updateStates() {
  var v = this.value;
  if (v) {
    hideAutoSelect('State');
    hideAutoSelect('City');
    var div = $('div.autoSelect.'+v);
    div.removeClass('hidden');
    var select = $('select', div);
    if (select.val()) $('div.autoSelect.'+select.val()).removeClass('hidden');
  }
}

function updateCities() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  if (v) {
    hideAutoSelect('City');
    $('div.autoSelect.'+v).removeClass('hidden');
  }
}

$(document).on('ready',function () {
  buildForms(data);
  $('[name=country]').on('change', updateStates);
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h3>Add Vendor</h3>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <form action="/add/vendors" method="post">
        <!-- ################# Our own in-house ID for this vendor #################-->
        <div class="top-row">
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>Create vendor ID<span class="req">*</span>
              <input placeholder="V00000">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ############################### Vendor name #################################-->
        <div class="top-row">
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>Vendor name<span class="req">*</span>
              <input placeholder="John">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ################################ Vendor type ################################-->
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            Vendor type<span class= "req">*</span>
            <select>
              <option selected="--">--</option>
            </select></label>
        </div>             
        <!-- ############################## Vendor location ##############################-->
        <div class="field-wrap country">         
          <label>Vendor origin<span class="req">*</span>
            <select name="country">
              <option selected= "--">--</option>
              <option value= "China" >China</option>
              <option value= "India" >India</option>
              <option value= "USA"  >USA</option>
            </select>
          </label>

       </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Below is my **/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb**

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

html{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

body{
    padding: 80px;
}

header {
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    min-width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
}

.nav {
    background: #232323;
    height: 60px;
    *display:inline;
    *zoom:1;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

.nav li a {
    font-size: 14px; 
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
}

#search {
    width: 357px;
    margin: 4px;
}
#search_text{
    width: 297px;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 52px;
    margin-right: 0;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    background: #494949;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color: white;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color: white;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: white;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color: white;
}
#search_text:focus {
    background: #5a5a5a;
}

#options a{
    border-left: 0 none;
}

.subnav {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    background: #232323;
}
.subnav li {
    float: none;
}
.subnav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
}
#options:hover .subnav {
    visibility: visible;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <ul class= "nav">
      <li><a class="active" href="/home">Home</a></li>
      <% if logged_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Profile", edit_user_path(current_user.id) %></li>
      <%end%>
      <li id= "options">
        <a href="#">Add</a>
        <ul class= "subnav">
            <li><%= link_to "Part", add_parts_path%></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Project", add_projects_path%></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Vendor", add_vendors_path%></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", inquires_path, method: :get %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path, method: :delete %></li>
      <li id= "search">
        <form action= "" method= "get">
            <input type="text" name="search_text" id= "search_text" placeholder="Search Page"/>
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you using turbolinks in your application?

Comment: Yes I have included turbolinks in my Gemfile

Comment: You should read through the turbolinks docs - especially [the part on idempotent transformations](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#making-transformations-idempotent). You can't just hook your jQuery into the ready event and expect it to work with turbolinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using turbolinks you should change ready for turbolinks:load.

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  buildForms(data);
  $('[name=country]').on('change', updateStates);
})
```

Comment: This seemed to fix the problem, although now there is a closely related problem. Now every time a country is selected, an **additional** state dropdown appears. i.e. select a country, and then change countries 3 times and you will have 4 state dropdowns

Comment: I would debug JavaScript, in particular before calling buildForms to check if it is called more than once. If not, check what is called when you change countries (should be updateStates) to see if it is called more than once. Even if called more than once it should not create additional drop downs, just make them visible. Check the updateStates code (or debug it) to see if there’s something wrong in this code.

Answer (score 0):

According to this link (https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#loading-your-applications-javascript-bundle), you should be using `<script>` elements in the `<head>` of your document.

Also you should consider adding `data-turbolinks-track="reload"` to your `script` element https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#reloading-when-assets-change

Comment: I edited my question to incorporate these changes to the code. Unfortunately, didn't work

Comment: I can't see the code in your link https://safe-waters-30326.herokuapp.com/add/vendors. Instead it's showing some errors. This one seems to be an issue: `application-cbd3cd4.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: That's odd... it is appearing on my end